# Python. Падает json.loads

Tags: python, json, сервер, клиент-сервер, flask

Привет. Возникла проблема при преобразовании строки в json. Есть сервачок, который обменивается с браузером и back-end данными. От браузера прилетает запрос, он перенаправляется движку. Движок высылает ответ. Ответ уходит браузеру и на консоль в виде преобразованного json. Вопрос в том, что первый раз я получаю ответ и всё происходит чудесно. Во второй раз вроде как проблема в том, что у меня прилетает 2 словаря, т.е. два json в одном ответе.

```
@app.route('/search/3', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def GetFromBrowser():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            connection = requests.get("http://localhost:8082/search/3", params = request.args)
        except:
            print("python: Unexpected connection")
            return ""
        strJson = connection.text[22:-2]
        dataJson = json.loads(strJson) ## Здесь происходит крах
        data = dataJson['result']['poi'][0]['features']
        PlotStat(data)
        return connection.text
    else:
        return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '127.0.0.1', port = '8080')
```

Крах выглядит так:

```
[2017-01-12 10:11:21,602] ERROR in app: Exception on /search/3 [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/mapsfullsearch/src/estimation/main.py", line 32, in GetFromBrowser
    dataJson = json.loads(strJson)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 7 - line 1 column 1185 (char 6 - 1184)
```

Comment: А какая содержимое у `strJson` ?

Comment: @faoxis, вероятно, там, действительно было несколько JSON. Проблема решается так:         `if (strJson[0] != "{"):
            strJson = "{" + connection.text[22:-2] + "}"`